# How do I fix broken .exe file association in Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, file-association

Somehow the file association for all .exe files has been deleted on my windows vista machine. For some reason the only thing I can open is Firefox. I think it was the result of a virus. So I have tried a couple registry edit fixes but none have worked. Has anyone run into this?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/q/354771/24500

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Click [here](http://www.winhelponline.com/fileasso/exefix_vista.zip) and unzip the file and apply the .reg file.

Comment: That did it. I thought I had tried that one already but I must not have! Thanks.

Comment: It would be nice if somebody could elaborate on what, "apply the .reg file" means.

Comment: Double click the .reg file, then press "yes" for each dialog that pops up.