# Incorrect File association for .exe files in Windows

Tags: file-extension

I accidentally chose 'open with this program this kind of file' for .exe files. Now, all the files with a .exe extension open with a particular program. My computer does not have an earlier restore point so I can't restore to an earlier time. How to revert my .exe extensions with appropriate applications?

Comment: Google the 'EXE Fix'. Many sites have the registry entry available. you'll need to use the CMD prompt to import it

Comment: [First link from shmoogle](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/17717edb-daa2-4e7f-adb2-c277d4619d46/how-to-delete-file-association-with-an-unwanted-program-i-dont-want-it-associate-with-any?forum=w7itprogeneral)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to repair a broken .EXE file association](http://superuser.com/questions/362827/how-to-repair-a-broken-exe-file-association), [How to fix .exe file association in Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/427434/how-to-fix-exe-file-association-in-windows), [How do I fix broken .exe file association in Windows Vista?](http://superuser.com/questions/127791/how-do-i-fix-broken-exe-file-association-in-windows-vista),

Comment: [How do you associate the .exe file extension with a program in Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/354771/how-do-you-associate-the-exe-file-extension-with-a-program-in-windows)

Comment: Hi John, in case if you intend to move your windows "file associations" to default, then please follow the [link1](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html) and [link2] (http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/how-do-i-change-a-file-association-back-to-default/b28a9112-c2a0-4672-a893-322f7239788e)

Answer (score 1):

First off, download [this link](http://www.dougknox.com/xp/fileassoc/xp_exe_fix.zip), which is a registry file. Hopefully, you can still open archives with Windows Explorer. Inside, you'll find a .REG file (contents below for XP).

Then, start Task Manager. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Escape</kbd> to do so. Click File, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while clicking on New Process. This will open the Command Prompt. Import the registry file by typing `REG IMPORT <filename>`. If you are not in the same folder as where that registry file is, include the full path.

If you need to create the REG file from scratch, open Notepad (or another PLAIN TEXT editor), copy and paste the code below, then save it with a .REG extension.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe]
@="exefile"
"Content Type"="application/x-msdownload"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.exe\PersistentHandler]
@="{098f2470-bae0-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile]
@="Application"
"EditFlags"=hex:38,07,00,00
"TileInfo"="prop:FileDescription;Company;FileVersion"
"InfoTip"="prop:FileDescription;Company;FileVersion;Create;Size"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\DefaultIcon]
@="%1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\open]
"EditFlags"=hex:00,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\open\command]
@="\"%1\" %*"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\runas]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\runas\command]
@="\"%1\" %*"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shellex]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shellex\DropHandler]
@="{86C86720-42A0-1069-A2E8-08002B30309D}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\PEAnalyser]
@="{09A63660-16F9-11d0-B1DF-004F56001CA7}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\PifProps]
@="{86F19A00-42A0-1069-A2E9-08002B30309D}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\ShimLayer Property Page]
@="{513D916F-2A8E-4F51-AEAB-0CBC76FB1AF8}"
```

If you're running Windows Vista or Seven, then [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2688326) has other steps for you:

1. Click the Start button and type `regedit` in the Search box
2. Right-click **Regedit.exe** in the returned list and click *Run as administrator*
3. Browse to the following registry key:
   **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.exe**
4. With `.exe` selected, right-click `(Default)` and click **Modify…**. Change the Value data to `exefile`
5. Browse to and then click on the following registry key:
   **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile**
6. With `exefileselected`, right-click `(Default)` and click **Modify…**
7. Change the Value data: to `"%1" %*`
8. Browse to and then click on the following registry key:
   **KEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\open**
9. With `openselected`, right-click `(Default)` and click **Modify…**
10. Change the Value data: to `"%1" %*`
11. Close the Registry Editor and restart your PC